# Register Different services using same class in my Laravel 5.7 Jobs?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the following class ony my Laravel App:

```
namespace App\Api\Consumers

class ShoppingCartApiConsumer
{
   private $baseUrl="https://shopping.example.com";

   private $apiUrl="";

   private $headers=[];

   public function __construct(string $apiKey, string $shoppingCartId)
   {
     $this->apiUrl=$baseUrl."/shoppingCart/$shoppingCartId";
     $this->headers["Authorization"]="Bearer $apiKey"];
   }

   // Rest of methods here
}
```

And I have the following Jobs:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class PrivateShoppingListConsumer implements ShouldQueue
{
   use Dispatchable;
   use InteractsWithQueue;
   use Queueable;

   private $item;

   public function __construct(string $item)
   {
     $this->item=$item
   }

   public function handle(ShoppingCartApiConsumer $cart):void
   {
      //Logic Implemented here
   }
}
```

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class WorkShoppingListConsumer implements ShouldQueue
{
   use Dispatchable;
   use InteractsWithQueue;
   use Queueable;

   private $item;

   public function __construct(string $item)
   {
     $this->item=$item
   }

   public function handle(ShoppingCartApiConssumer $cart):void
   {
      if($item != "computer"){
        return;
      }

      //rest of code here

   }
}
```

The `PrivateShoppingListConsumer` needs the following instance of `ShoppingCartApiConsumer`

```
$config=config('shoppingCart');
$consumer=new ShoppingListConsumer($config['api_key'],$config['private_shopping_cart_id']);
```

And the `WorkShoppingListConsumer` needs the follwoing instance of `ShoppingListConsumer`:

```
$config=config('shoppingCart');
$consumer=new ShoppingListConsumer($config['api_key'],$config['work_shopping_cart_id']);
```

The fonfig for the instance initialization is the following:

```
return [
  'api_key' => env("API_KEY"),
  'private_shopping_cart_id' => env("PRIVATE_SHOPPING_CART_ID");
  'work_shopping_cart_id' => env("WORK_SHOPPING_CART_ID");
]
```

So I want to know how I can pass the following Instances to each job using laravel's Service Container? Because both `WorkShoppingListConsumer` and `PrivateShoppingListConsumer` need the appropriate class instance in order my business logic to work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to define a custom service provider based upon [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#class-structure) and service container [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers) for example:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ShoppingCartApiConsumerProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function register():void
  {
    $config=config('shoppingCart');
    $privateConsumer=new ShoppingListConsumer($config['api_key'],$config['private_shopping_cart_id']);
    $workConsumer=new ShoppingListConsumer($config['api_key'],$config['work_shopping_cart_id']);

    $this->app->bindMethod(PrivateShoppingListConsumer::class.'@handle', function ($job, $app) use ($privateConsumer) {
            return $job->handle($privateConsumer);
});

$this->app->bindMethod(WorkShoppingListConsumer::class.'@handle', function ($job, $app) use ($workConsumer) {
            return $job->handle($workConsumer);
});
    //Append here more jobs on how to be dispatched
  }
}
```